# Get access token for twitter authentication using JS OAuthSimple Library

Tags: oauth, twitter, access-token

I am developing a mobile app using HTML5 + PhoneGap **(there's not ANY backend server side)**.
I'm using **OAuthSimple** Library to sign in but I can't get the last step to get the access_token. Did anybody used this library and got it ? Can you give me a code sample?

I've red the following doc but it was not helpful al all:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth#Acquiring_a_request_token

Thks!

Comment: Haven't used that library specifically but I have used a lot of other OAuth libraries (and written my own). Where does it go wrong?

Comment: its very hard to find what is not working without any error/exceptions and details

Comment: This helped me solve my own issue with this library, but you should really post this as a real answer and can accept it :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi guys thanks for your comments. I've figured out this issue. I was not doing a good sign. Once I've completed the authorization step, I've used the new auth token and it's working now. Next I'll paste you an extract of code with the solution: var signed = Oauth.sign({ action: "GET", path: accessTokenUrl, method:'HMAC-SHA1', parameters: { oauth_verifier: pin /* obtained by the user / }, signatures: requestTokenResponse / once it's authorized */ });

Comment: Hey, I'm currently having almost this exact same problem. Any way you could share your code or post it? It would be a huge help!

Comment: @blackdragon hey I have to use it in IBM Worklight based on PhoneGap. Can you help me out?